# Plasma Discover uninstalled with the latest package update now cannot be reinstalled

Tags: package-management, updates, kubuntu, kde, plasma

While doing the package update this morning, I got an information that these packages are going to be removed:

- plasma-discover
- plasma-discover-snap-backend
- ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt

Cannot tell you exactly what packages were recently updated (don't even know how to check it).

Anyway, I said, "ye, whatever is needed for the update. If I need these later, I'll just install 'em again".

However, now it doesn't let me install plasma-discover with the following dependency issue while trying to fix it:

```
~ » sudo apt-get install plasma-discover                                                               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 plasma-discover : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
------------------------------------------------------------
~ » sudo apt-get install software-properties-kde
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 software-properties-kde : Depends: python3-software-properties (= 0.96.24.32.1) but 0.96.24.32.3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
------------------------------------------------------------
~ » sudo apt-get install python3-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-software-properties is already the newest version (0.96.24.32.3).
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libamd2 libbabl-0.1-0 libcamd2 libccolamd2 libcholmod3 libgegl-0.3-0 libmetis5 libsnapd-glib1 libsnapd-qt1
  libumfpack5
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Now I don't really know if it is an issue with something I've done or it's just a dependency issue that I gotta wait till is resolved.

I'd appreciate any advice. Could do with Plasma Discover being back in my KDE...

Cheers!

Comment: I'm guessing you're on Kubuntu 18.04. Was it a clean install or an upgrade? Does `sudo apt update` throw up any errors, warnings, etc? Have you installed any `ppa` or `.deb` files from outside the standard repositories? Going by what's being suggested as removeable, did you install `octave` from a ppa or from somewhere else and then "delete" it?

Comment: Clean Kubuntu straight to 18.04 earlier this month. `apt update` no issues at all. Installed `.deb` with one app (Insync - Google Drive sync) but I had it before and it never give me any troubles. With regards to `octave`, if [this is what you mean](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) I never had it installed.

Comment: Just tried these which I found on other forum hoping it would have something to do with the sources:
`sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo apt-get install plasma-discover`
still the same issue:
`plasma-discover : Depends: ubuntu-release-upgrader-qt but it is not going to be installed
                   Recommends: software-properties-kde but it is not going to be installed`

Comment: Did you look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/316264/insync-messed-up-apt-and-i-cant-do-apt-get-update-upgrade

Comment: I've just tried it now, but didn't help at all. Same old, same old

Comment: Have you run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` recently? There were Discover-related updates today for me.

Comment: This is crazy, but what I get now is a bunch of python3 related errors every time I run apt or dpkg ... here's a paste from apt-get upgrade: https://pastebin.com/U2EGthiS Haven't yet dug into this to see what I can figure out. Will update once I have.

Comment: Your pastebin shows `systemd` as auto-removeable!!! If it were my system, I'd just do a clean install all over again.

Comment: I think there's no point digging into that more. I'll do a fresh re-install. I got my /home on a different partition, so it should be fine

Comment: Did the reinstall - problem solved :)